# Adding Drawer Layout in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am working on a app in which I already have a Drawer Layout in MainActivity. Now I want to add new activity which should contain another drawer. Is it possible to have two drawer in a App like this?

Comment: Yes you can have different activities with different Drawer Layouts. You can even use the same layout and pass different List of items to the list in Drawer Layout

Comment: I don't see why not. Depending on the structure of the App, it _may or may not_ be redundant, but it should be possible. As long as it is an Activity.

Comment: Of course you can. But why you did not try it and get result before asking ? :)

Comment: I have try it but no result

Comment: Please look at this question , help me if you can. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487058/unable-to-start-new-activityandroid